# On Close of Alert Window navigate to HomeScreen JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to navigate to the home screen when a js alert is closed?

So I have triggered an alert

```
.then((message) => alert("Bestellung wird bearbeitet")
```

& I want that you get redirected to the Home Screen when you press on the close button.

Is there a way to accomplish this behaviour?

I tried adding

> window.location.href = 'index.html'

after the alert button, but I get redirected instantly, so the alert button doesn't even appear. But I want to be redirected after the alert button is closed.

The attempt:

```
function sendEmail() {
    Email.send({
      SecureToken: "a",
      To: "b",
      From: "c@gmail.com",
      Subject: "Bestellung",
      Body:
        "Body"
    }).then((message) => alert("Bestellung wird bearbeitet"), 
    window.location.href = 'index.html');
  }
```

Comment: alert() halts the execution until user closes the alert dialog so you could just add a statement like: `window.location.href = 'yourhomescreen'` after the alert() call. Am I wrong?

Comment: You will get a better answer if you provide valid code in your question.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I face the problem that I get redirect Instantly, before the alert even appears. Any suggestions?

p.s posted that what I tried in the question

Comment: Thanks for adding the function. No your code is not correct. See [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). Notice how it uses `{` and `}` to combine multiple statements.

Comment: `.then((message) => {alert("Bestellung wird bearbeitet"); window.location.href = 'index.html';}`

Comment: always the little thing ^^, thanks! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: & @DiegoDeVita :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) the second arguments passed to `then()` it's the handler for the rejected case. You were passing a second argument using `,` instead of wrapping a sequence of statements in the closure function body.

This is the way for the second instruction to be executed after the user closed the alert dialog:

```
.then((message) => {
  alert("Bestellung wird bearbeitet");
  window.location.href = 'index.html';
}
```